# Comparing 2 datasets in order to keep only participants who completed 75% of trials using R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset where participants completed trials of a task. There are 100 regular trials and 10 practice trials. For this task we only want to keep the trials that people got correct. I have made a separate dataset that has my data without the outliers and incorrect trials. Now, I am stuck because I need to find a way to only keep the participants who still have at least 75% of their data.

To simplify and not post the entire large dataset it looks something like this:

```
subject latency 
0003     454
0003     500
0003     600
0004     457
0004     600
0005     700
```

So subjects are in one column and their latency is in another column. The second dataset is smaller because trials were removed. I couldn't really find a good way to compare the 2 datasets and only keep subject IDs that kept 75% or more of their data.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

If your two data sets are called `dt1` and `dt2`:

First find the number of trials per subject and merge the before and after tables:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt1)
setDT(dt2)

dt3 <- merge(
  dt1[, .N, subject], 
  dt2[, .N, subject],
  by = "subject"
)
```

The subjects you want to keep are those who have > 0.75 observations remaining:

```
subjToKeep <- dt3[, percRemaining := N.y / N.x][percRemaining >= 0.75, subject]

dt2[subject %in% subjToKeep]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple `dplyr` solution

```
# example of full dataset
df_full = data.frame(subject = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4),
                     latency = 1:13) 

# example of smaller dataset
df_small = data.frame(subject = c(1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                      latency = c(2,5,6,7,8,10,12))


library(dplyr)

df_full %>% count(subject) %>%                              # count rows for each subject in full dataset
  left_join(df_small %>% count(subject), by="subject") %>%  # count rows for each subject in small dataset and join
  filter(n.y / n.x >= 0.75) %>%                             # keep only subjects where we have 75% or more of their data
  pull(subject) -> subj_vec                                 # save the subjects as a vector

# use that vector to filter your smaller dataset
df_small %>% filter(subject %in% subj_vec)  

#   subject latency
# 1       2       5
# 2       2       6
# 3       2       7
# 4       3       8
# 5       3      10
# 6       3      12
```

Comment: Thank you so much, success!